# Exponential Moving Average - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been using the simple_statistics gem, but im looking to calculate the EMA on the last x records. For example (when calculating WMA)

```
@stockticker.ema10 = s.stocktickers.last(10).map(&:current_price).map{|f| f.to_f}.wma
```

I was wondering if anyone can provide advise on how I got about calculating the EMA in rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [Moving Averages](https://github.com/bradcater/moving_averages) gem might be what you're looking for.  Here is a copy of their `exponential_moving_average` method for reference as well.

```
class Array 
  def exponential_moving_average(idx=nil, tail=nil)
    idx, tail = idx_and_tail_or_defaults(idx, tail)
    valid_for_ma(idx, tail)
    alpha = 2.0 / (tail + 1)
    n = (1..tail).to_a.map{|tidx| (1 - alpha) ** (tidx - 1) * self[idx - tidx + 1]}.sum
    d = (1..tail).to_a.map{|tidx| (1 - alpha) ** (tidx - 1)}.sum
    n / d
   end
   alias_method :ema, :exponential_moving_average
end
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I did see this gem before but didn't read past the example which showed SMA only :)

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of [`Statsample-timeseries`](https://rubygems.org/gems/statsample-timeseries) gem which is an extension of [Statsample](https://rubygems.org/gems/statsample), an advance statistical suite in Ruby. It has quite many statistical methods (including [EMA](http://rubydoc.info/gems/statsample-timeseries/0.0.3/Statsample/TimeSeries/Series%3aema)) which you can perform on your data.

If you need any assistance, I will be very happy to help out. :)

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for this, a great gem, but a little over complicated for what I am looking for :)